# I'm stuck in the creating of a Board game in python

Tags: python

I have an excercise to do and I'm stuck. It's the board game Alak, not much known, that I have to code in python. I can link the execrcise with the rules so you can help me better. The code has the main part and the library with all the procedures and function.

```
    from Library_alak import *
n = 0
while n < 1:
    n = int(input('Saisir nombre de case strictement positif : '))
loop = True
player = 1
player2 = 2
removed = [-1]
board = newboard(n)
display(board, n)

while loop:
    i = select(board, n, player, removed)
    print(i)
    board = put(board, player, i)
    display(board, n)
    capture(board, n, player, player2)
    loop = True if again(board, n, player, removed) is True else False
    if player == 1 and loop:
        player, player2 = 2, 1
    elif player == 2 and loop:
        player, player2 = 1, 2
win(board, n)
print(win(board, n))
```

And here is the library:

```
def newboard(n):
    board = ([0] * n)
    return board


def display(board, n):
    for i in range(n):
        if board[i] == 1:
            print('X', end=' ')
        elif board[i] == 2:
            print('O', end=' ')
        else:
            print(' . ', end=' ')


def capture(board, n, player, player2):
    for place in range(n):
        if place == player:
            place_beginning = place
            while board[place] != player:
                place_end = place
            if board[place + x] == player:
                return board
            else:
                return board


def again(board, n, player, removed):
    for p in board(0):
        if p == 0:
            if p not in removed:
                return True
            else:
                return False


def possible(n, removed, player, i, board):
    for p in range(n + 1):
        if p == 1:
            if board[p-1] == 0:
                if p not in removed:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False


def win(board, n):
    piecesp1 = 0
    piecesp2 = 0

    for i in board(0):
        if i == 1:
            piecesp1 += 1
        else:
            piecesp2 += 1
        if piecesp1 > piecesp2:
            print('Victory : Player 1')
        elif piecesp2 > piecesp1:
            print('Victory : Player 2')
        else:
            return 'Equality'


def select(board, n, player, removed):
    loop = True
    while loop:
        print('player', player)
        i = int(input('Enter number of boxes : '))
        loop = False if possible(n, removed, player, i, board)is True else True
        return i


def put(board, player, i):
    i -= 1
    if board[i] == 0:
        if player == 1:
            board[i] = 1
            return board
        else:
            board[i] = 2
            return board
    else:
        put(board, player, i)
```

So my problems here are that I have few errors, the first one is that when I enter the number '1' when asked to enter a number of boxes ( which is the place to play on ) nothing happens. Then when entering any other number, either the error is :     if board[place + x] == player:
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
or there seems to be a problem with the :     if board[place + x] == player:
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

I would appreciate a lot if anyone could help me. I'm conscious that it might not be as detailed as it should be and that you maybe don't get it all but you can contact me for more.

Rules of the Alak game:

> Black and white take turns placing stones on the line. Unlike Go, this placement is compulsory if a move is available; if no move is possible, the game is over.
>
> No stone may be placed in a location occupied by another stone, or in a location where a stone of your own colour has just been removed. The latter condition keeps the game from entering a neverending loop of stone placement and capture, known in Go as ko.
>
> If placing a stone causes one or two groups of enemy stones to no longer have any adjacent empty spaces--liberties, as in Go--then those stones are removed. As the above rule states, the opponent may not play in those locations on their following turn.
>
> If placing a stone causes one or two groups of your own colour to no longer have any liberties, the stones are not suicided, but instead are safe and not removed from play.

Comment: You want Python to calculate `place + x` when issueing `board[place + x] == player` but you never told Python what `x` is. That's what the error message is saying.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? You're trying to use a variable `x`, but `x` doesn't exist.

Comment: `loop = False if possible(n, removed, player, i, board)is True else True` is a convoluted way to write `loop = not possible(n, removed, player, i, board)`.

Comment: Your loop in `select` doesn't work because you've put `return` inside the loop body, not outside.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the loop, now I'm struggling with the capture function, I don't know how to set it up

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't use "player2" as a variable, there's an easier way, just use "player" which take the value 1 or 2 according to the player. You know, something like that : player = 1 if x%2==0 else 2
and x is just a increasing int from 0 until the end of the game.

Comment: If you can't answer the question you should rather use the comment option.